# 100% locally-working Yii2 site throws errors on production server

Tags: php, yii2, production

My Yii2 site worked perfectly on my local machine, however since I've uploaded it to the production server I'm getting some odd issues.

The problem is that, while I can add a record using the system, I can't delete or even view the record once it's created. The error is 403 "You are not allowed to perform this action."

I was using the below 'access' rules in my SiteController but I still have the issue even when this section is commented out.

```
'access' => [
   'class' => AccessControl::className(),
   'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'create', 'edit', 'index'],
   'rules' => [
           [
           'actions' => ['show'],
           'allow' => true,
                   'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                        'actions' => ['index', 'logout', 'create', 'edit'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
        ],
],
```

Edit: two comments around Windows/Linux case sensitivity. The first issue (which I've now deleted from my question) was caused by exactly this.

However the second issue around 403 forbidden issues is still persisting.

I can see the main "index" of each view fine, but trying to "view", "update" or "delete" is not working. As I said, "add" works, but then when it takes me to the "view" action after adding, I get the 403.

The full text of the error, as I'm now ALSO getting the same problem on my local server, is as follows:

```
exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php:154 
Stack trace: 
#0 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\AccessControl.php(137): yii\filters\AccessControl->denyAccess(Object(yii\web\User)) 
#1 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(75): yii\filters\AccessControl->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#2 [internal function]: yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter(Object(yii\base\ActionEvent)) 
#3 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(545): call_user_func(Array, Object(yii\base\ActionEvent)) 
#4 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(272): yii\base\Component->trigger('beforeAction', Object(yii\base\ActionEvent)) 
#5 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(164): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#6 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(154): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction)) 
#7 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('view', Array) 
#8 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('job/view', Array) 
#9 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request)) 
#10 D:\Websites\cabana\advanced\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run() 
#11 {main}
```

Is there anything I should have done to put my site online? Like switch to "production" mode or something? Because I took the files from my local machine, uploaded them as-is to the server, exported and restored the MySQL database and updated the database connection details, but that's all I did.

Comment: you  have Windows in localhost and linux on production ?

Comment: Exactly my guess. Keep in mind that on windows file names are case-insensitive while they are case-sensitive in linux environments

Comment: Thanks for the super fast responses, people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
'access' => [
   'class' => AccessControl::className(),
   'only' => ['logout', 'signup', 'create', 'edit','index','view','update','delete'],
   'rules' => [
       [
       'actions' => ['show'],
       'allow' => true,
               'roles' => ['?'],
       ],
       [
       'actions' => ['index', 'logout', 'create', 'edit','view','update','delete'],
       'allow' => true,
       'roles' => ['@'],
       ],
  ],
],
```

you need to specify the rule for those 'view','update','delete' otherwise you will not be able to access.

Comment: I've added the exact code above in place of the access section I had before, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: please share more info. are you generating all using standart gii tool?

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I forgot that I added a version of access control rules to my individual route controllers and they were responsible for the 403. Thanks for your very kind assistance!